# 1 column beamerposter

Tags: beamer, beamerposter, posters

I would like to use the beamerpackage to create a 1 column poster. The dimensions should be 16 inches, 14 inch box and 1 inch of white space on the right and left edges of the poster. I plan to have 3 of these 1 column posters, measuring a total of 48x48 inches when placed side by side. This allows the poster to be carried in a small 18 inch tube, which is easier to bring as carry-on luggage.

My attempt below fails, as it makes two pages and does not make a nice title.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Jacobs Landscape Poster
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.1 (14/06/14)
%
% Created by:
% Computational Physics and Biophysics Group, Jacobs University
% https://teamwork.jacobs-university.de:8443/confluence/display/CoPandBiG/LaTeX+Poster
% 
% Further modified by:
% Nathaniel Johnston (nathaniel@njohnston.ca)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[final]{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage[scale=1.24]{beamerposter} % Use the beamerposter package for laying out the poster

\usetheme{confposter} % Use the confposter theme supplied with this template

\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=ngreen,bg=white} % Colors of the block titles
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=white} % Colors of the body of blocks
\setbeamercolor{block alerted title}{fg=white,bg=dblue!70} % Colors of the highlighted block titles
\setbeamercolor{block alerted body}{fg=black,bg=dblue!10} % Colors of the body of highlighted blocks
% Many more colors are available for use in beamerthemeconfposter.sty

%-----------------------------------------------------------
% Define the column widths and overall poster size
% To set effective sepwid, onecolwid and twocolwid values, first choose how many columns you want and how much separation you want between columns
% In this template, the separation width chosen is 0.024 of the paper width and a 4-column layout
% onecolwid should therefore be (1-(# of columns+1)*sepwid)/# of columns e.g. (1-(4+1)*0.024)/4 = 0.22
% Set twocolwid to be (2*onecolwid)+sepwid = 0.464
% Set threecolwid to be (3*onecolwid)+2*sepwid = 0.708

\newlength{\sepwid}
\newlength{\onecolwid}
\newlength{\twocolwid}
\newlength{\threecolwid}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{16in}
\setlength{\paperheight}{48in}
%\setlength{\paperwidth}{48in} % A0 width: 46.8in
%\setlength{\paperheight}{36in} % A0 height: 33.1in
\setlength{\sepwid}{0.063\paperwidth} % Separation width (white space) between columns
\setlength{\onecolwid}{0.87\paperwidth} % Width of one column
%\setlength{\sepwid}{0.024\paperwidth} % Separation width (white space) between columns
%\setlength{\onecolwid}{0.22\paperwidth} % Width of one column
\setlength{\twocolwid}{0.464\paperwidth} % Width of two columns
\setlength{\threecolwid}{0.708\paperwidth} % Width of three columns
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.5in} % Reduce the top margin size
%-----------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{graphicx}  % Required for including images

\usepackage{booktabs} % Top and bottom rules for tables

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title{Unnecessarily Complicated Research Title} % Poster title

\author{John Smith, James Smith and Jane Smith} % Author(s)

\institute{Department and University Name} % Institution(s)

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\addtobeamertemplate{block end}{}{\vspace*{2ex}} % White space under blocks
\addtobeamertemplate{block alerted end}{}{\vspace*{2ex}} % White space under highlighted (alert) blocks

\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{2ex} % White space under figures
\setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{2ex} % White space under equations

\begin{frame}[t][fragile] % The whole poster is enclosed in one beamer frame

\begin{columns}[t] % The whole poster consists of three major columns, the second of which is split into two columns twice - the [t] option aligns each column's content to the top

\begin{column}{\sepwid}\end{column} % Empty spacer column

\begin{column}{\onecolwid} % The first column

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   OBJECTIVES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{alertblock}{Objectives}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur, nunc tellus pulvinar tortor, commodo eleifend risus arcu sed odio:
\begin{itemize}
\item Mollis dignissim, magna augue tincidunt dolor, interdum vestibulum urna
\item Sed aliquet luctus lectus, eget aliquet leo ullamcorper consequat. Vivamus eros sem, iaculis ut euismod non, sollicitudin vel orci.
\item Nascetur ridiculus mus.  
\item Euismod non erat. Nam ultricies pellentesque nunc, ultrices volutpat nisl ultrices a.
\end{itemize}

\end{alertblock}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INTRODUCTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{block}{Introduction}

Lorem ipsum dolor \textbf{sit amet}, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed commodo molestie porta. Sed ultrices scelerisque sapien ac commodo. Donec ut volutpat elit. Sed laoreet accumsan mattis. Integer sapien tellus, auctor ac blandit eget, sollicitudin vitae lorem. Praesent dictum tempor pulvinar. Suspendisse potenti. Sed tincidunt varius ipsum, et porta nulla suscipit et. Etiam congue bibendum felis, ac dictum augue cursus a. \textbf{Donec} magna eros, iaculis sit amet placerat quis, laoreet id est. In ut orci purus, interdum ornare nibh. Pellentesque pulvinar, nibh ac malesuada accumsan, urna nunc convallis tortor, ac vehicula nulla tellus eget nulla. Nullam lectus tortor, \textit{consequat tempor hendrerit} quis, vestibulum in diam. Maecenas sed diam augue.

This statement requires citation \cite{Smith:2012qr}.

\end{block}

%------------------------------------------------

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{placeholder.jpg}
\caption{Figure caption}
\end{figure}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{column} % End of the first column

\end{columns} % End of all the columns in the poster

\end{frame} % End of the enclosing frame

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you are concerned about the poster transport, maybe a poster printed on fabric could be something that interests you: https://www.google.com/search?q=print+on+fabric+poster

Comment: Two syntax errors: it should be `\begin{frame}[t,fragile]` and you must to have anything else in the line after `\end{frame}` if you use a fragile frame. With these errors fixed it will only produce a single page.

Comment: I understand putting together the columns next to each other, but how will you handle the title? Will it be printed on a 4th page in landscape format?

Comment: Thank you @samcarter. I will go with fabric, so as to keep everything less complicated.

Comment: Oh, good to hear! Here also a few ideas for after the conference: https://twitter.com/emeegray/status/563025236267106305 :)

Comment: I recommend going full latex. Design your poster with LaTeX, print it on latex, and after the conference, cut it up and make latex clothing.

Comment: @thymaro this solves another issue: you don't need to know the exact dimensions available for your poster, you can just stretch it to the available poster area :) Also good if it is raining on the way to the conference!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Latex Answer

Instead of manually messing with the page dimensions I would use the `\geometry` interface from the package of the same name. This allows you to specify the papersize and the margins.

Then you can leave out your empty dummy column and use one column of the width `\textwidth`

Please also note that

- the it should be `[t,fragile]`  instead of `[t][fragile]`
- if you want to use a fragile frame (which is not necessary at all in your example and just complicates things) you must not have anything else in the line \end{frame}
- you don't need the `graphicx` package with beamer

---

### Columns

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[scale=1.24]{beamerposter}
\usetheme{confposter}

\geometry{papersize={16in,32in},margin=1in}

\title{Unnecessarily Complicated Research Title} % Poster title
\author{John Smith, James Smith and Jane Smith} % Author(s)
\institute{Department and University Name} % Institution(s)

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t,fragile] 

\begin{columns}[t]

\begin{column}{\textwidth} % The first column

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   OBJECTIVES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{alertblock}{Objectives}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur, nunc tellus pulvinar tortor, commodo eleifend risus arcu sed odio:
\begin{itemize}
\item Mollis dignissim, magna augue tincidunt dolor, interdum vestibulum urna
\item Sed aliquet luctus lectus, eget aliquet leo ullamcorper consequat. Vivamus eros sem, iaculis ut euismod non, sollicitudin vel orci.
\item Nascetur ridiculus mus.  
\item Euismod non erat. Nam ultricies pellentesque nunc, ultrices volutpat nisl ultrices a.
\end{itemize}

\end{alertblock}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INTRODUCTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{block}{Introduction}

Lorem ipsum dolor \textbf{sit amet}, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed commodo molestie porta. Sed ultrices scelerisque sapien ac commodo. Donec ut volutpat elit. Sed laoreet accumsan mattis. Integer sapien tellus, auctor ac blandit eget, sollicitudin vitae lorem. Praesent dictum tempor pulvinar. Suspendisse potenti. Sed tincidunt varius ipsum, et porta nulla suscipit et. Etiam congue bibendum felis, ac dictum augue cursus a. \textbf{Donec} magna eros, iaculis sit amet placerat quis, laoreet id est. In ut orci purus, interdum ornare nibh. Pellentesque pulvinar, nibh ac malesuada accumsan, urna nunc convallis tortor, ac vehicula nulla tellus eget nulla. Nullam lectus tortor, \textit{consequat tempor hendrerit} quis, vestibulum in diam. Maecenas sed diam augue.

This statement requires citation \cite{Smith:2012qr}.

\end{block}

%------------------------------------------------

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{Figure caption}
\end{figure}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{column} % End of the first column

\end{columns} % End of all the columns in the poster

\end{frame}
 % End of the enclosing frame

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Title

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[scale=1.24]{beamerposter}
\usetheme{confposter}

\geometry{papersize={32in,16in},margin=1in}

\title{Unnecessarily Complicated Research Title} % Poster title
\author{John Smith, James Smith and Jane Smith} % Author(s)
\institute{Department and University Name} % Institution(s)

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame} 

\begin{block}{Abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Combined:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

## Non-LaTeX answer

In the question the OP indicates that he/she/it tries such a difficult approach to easier transport the poster in hand luggage.

This problem can be avoided. Instead of worrying about the transport of a poster printed on paper, consider using a fabric poster. It is printed on fabric and is therefore foldable and fits in the hand luggage.

For a more thorough review of the available options than I can offer here, see e.g. http://www.astrobetter.com/blog/2015/03/25/fabric-conference-posters-ftw/

### After the conference

Make sure to not throw away your poster, it can be re-purposed as

[image]
(image from https://twitter.com/emeegray/status/563025236267106305)

[image]
(image from https://medium.com/@cllantz/got-a-fabric-poster-sew-yourself-a-tote-1b4cf60530dd)

(this will solve the problem of not being recognisable without the poster tube at the airport)

Comment: Friends, samcarter *did* post this answer (she confirmed with me), because she thinks it is a solution to the underlying problem, instead of the workaround asked for in the question, confirmed by the OP's comment https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/462220/1-column-beamerposter/462401?noredirect=1#comment1162501_462220 In case user deem it to be too off-topic, please feel free to delete.

Comment: Printing posters on fabric actually seems like a good idea. The possibility had never occurred to me.

Comment: @Circumscribe Thanks for worrying about my account status! These fabric posters are a relatively new invention, I first saw one maybe 2 years ago and their number seem to slowly, but steadily increasing since then.

Comment: @Circumscribe Thanks for the welcome back and the +2 :)